# Django Admin Choicefield Error

Tags: django, admin, choicefield

I'm trying to set the Gender for my Users in Admin but get the Error

> `Value u"[u'm']" is not a valid choice.`

admin.py

```
class PlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('m', 'Male'),
        ('f', 'Female'),
    )
...
gender = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label="Gender", choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
...

class Meta:
    model = Player


class PlayerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PlayerForm


admin.site.register(Player, PlayerAdmin)
```

models.py (Player Model)

```
class Player(AbstractBaseUser):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('m', 'Male'),
        ('f', 'Female'),
    )
    ...
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    ...
```

Fun fact: The form does display the correct default value from dadabase in admin.

POST Payload when trying to submit the Form:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary009tVyo4cRJvIAnC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="gender"

m
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that the DB is Postgres 8.4 and the column in question is a

```
VARCHAR(1)
```

Comment: Can you post the traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using [`MultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#MultipleChoiceField):

```
gender = forms.MultipleChoiceField(label="Gender", choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

It's going to save gender to a "list".  Resulting in:

```
>>> gender = ['m']
```

You need to use [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#ChoiceField) which is used to select a single thing:

```
gender = forms.ChoiceField(label="Gender", choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> gender = 'm'
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it. Must have "accidentially" selected MultipleChoiceField which was never my intention.